# how to save links in a database and display them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, link-to

i am working on a rails blog app, and i need to add user tags on post. 
example i write and post the following; 'my dogs name is john. #dogs'
i want dogs to be clickable text on that post.
how do i display a clickable #dogs text on view to a route /dogs.
on a regular views page we just use a link_to helper,
how can i use that or anything else to do so

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [view helper](https://mixandgo.com/learn/the-beginners-guide-to-rails-helpers) and pass the text into that view helper. The View helper can parse the text using regular expressions and replace the results with a link.